# How to constrain a UIImageView inside another view?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, core-graphics, ios-universal-app

I have a universal iOS swift project in xcode, and am having trouble getting the sizes of a `UIImageView` right. The XIB structure is as follows:

`View
|-- Card (View)
     |-- CoverImage (UIImageView)`

`View` is loaded into a `UIScrollView` by `ViewController.swift`. `Card` has top, bottom, trailing, and leading constraints set up so that there is a 20px 'margin' around it. `Card` also has rounded corners. `CoverImage` has similar constraints, with top, trailing, and leading being set to superview and bottom being defined in `viewDidLoad()` as 40% of the height of `Card`. The problem is that the width of `CoverImage` exceeds the width of `Card`, with the excess not being displayed. As a result, when I try to round the top corners of `CoverImage`, only the Top Left corner is rounded.

Setting `leadingConstraint.constant` or `trailingConstraint.constant` to `0` seems to have no effect, as the top right corner still remains unrounded.

How can I set `CoverImage`'s constraints properly so that it has the correct size? Is it an issue with the constraints I'm setting in the XIB, or is there a better way to define the size of a child view?

For reference, this is the controller swift file for the View containing `Card` and `CoverImage`:

```
class CardViewController: UIViewController {

// MARK: Connect All Subviews/Objects
@IBOutlet weak var card: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var coverImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var topConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var trailingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var leadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // MARK: Draw Card
    card.layer.cornerRadius = 2
    card.layer.shadowRadius = 3
    card.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.15;
    card.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1)
    card.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    // MARK: Draw Cover Image
    let imageViewShape : CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    imageViewShape.bounds = coverImage.frame
    imageViewShape.position = coverImage.center
    imageViewShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: coverImage.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [UIRectCorner.TopRight, UIRectCorner.TopLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 2, height: 2)).CGPath
    coverImage.layer.mask = imageViewShape
    bottomConstraint.constant = card.frame.height * 0.4

}
}
```

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you try to set the bounds of CAShapeLayer on `viewDidLoad` you'll get incorrect dimensions as for the superview isn't rendered on the device at the moment yet; it should be created on `viewDidAppear`.

Now that we have the correct frame we have to position it properly in superview and by default the mask we append does inherit the constraints of the view it's applied to, thus we have to adjust the origin point of it by 20 pixels on both axis.

The code I used to make it all look fine as you requested it to:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    let imageViewShape : CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    imageViewShape.frame = coverImage.frame
    imageViewShape.bounds = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: coverImage.bounds.origin.x + 20, y: coverImage.bounds.origin.y + 20), size: coverImage.bounds.size)
    imageViewShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: coverImage.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [UIRectCorner.TopRight, UIRectCorner.TopLeft, UIRectCorner.BottomLeft, UIRectCorner.BottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)).CGPath
    coverImage.layer.mask = imageViewShape

}
```

Comment: Did this answer your question? If so, please accept it, if not – please let me know how I can improve it!